# Auto +6 increment while dragging cells in excel

Tags: excel

So, I got an excel with two sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2, in which I transfer data from the first to the second using the formula: **=IF(INT(+INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1"))< 42900,0,+INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1"))** (the cells are custom format dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss). In Sheet1, the cells are organized in groups made out of 6 columns (in this example, A being the first column within the group).

In Sheet2, when I drag the cell containing said formula to the cell on the right, the formula remains the same. I want so that when I drag the cell, A1 will become G1, basically incrementing the column "number" by 6 jumping to the next group of 6 columns.

Is there a way of doing this **WITHOUT** using any coding. I need to avoid coding at all costs in order to avoid further complications.

P.S. I apologize if my explanation and title are somewhat vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter below formula anywhere in `Column 1` and drag/copy across (to right)

```
=IF(INT(INDIRECT("Sheet1!" & ADDRESS(1,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)*6,1)+1)))< 42900,0,INDIRECT("Sheet1!" & ADDRESS(1,FLOOR((COLUMN()-1)*6,1)+1)))
```

This formula will refer to cells `$A$1,$G$1,$M$1,$S$1,.....`

If you have to use this formula in say `Column B` then change `(COLUMN()-1)` to `(COLUMN()-2)` and likewise for `Column C,D,E,....` use `(COLUMN()-3),(COLUMN()-4),(COLUMN()-5),....` respectively.